# How to sort a WBS correctly in PowerBI (Dax)

Tags: sorting, powerbi, dax

I have a WBS from MS Project Online which is TEXT format e.g.
1,
1.1,
1.1.10,
1.1.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5ob1.png)

I can't convert to decimal or whole number.

Ideally I'm looking to sort so 1.1.2 is before 1.1.10.

Comment: I seriously answered your question and then deleted because I saw the post before you made the edit :-P. I thought I had answered incorrectly. I have reposted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sort column by transforming your data in Power Query. See snippet below.

[image]

If you use the M code posted below, you should be able to make a blank query and paste in the code to see exactly how I arrived at the sort column.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtQDQqVYHQjLCM4yhrNM4CxTOMsMzjKHsyzgLEs4y9AAwYTYYgS1zRhur7GeERIL6IJYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [WBS = _t]),
    #"Duplicate Column: The WBS Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "WBS", "WBS - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter: Use Period" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicate Column: The WBS Column", "WBS - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"WBS - Copy.1", "WBS - Copy.2", "WBS - Copy.3"}),
    #"Changed Type: Make Split Columns Number Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter: Use Period",{{"WBS - Copy.1", Int64.Type}, {"WBS - Copy.2", Int64.Type}, {"WBS - Copy.3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows: In Order of the WBS Hierarchy" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type: Make Split Columns Number Types",{{"WBS - Copy.1", Order.Ascending}, {"WBS - Copy.2", Order.Ascending}, {"WBS - Copy.3", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index: Index Will Serve as Sort" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows: In Order of the WBS Hierarchy", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Column: Named Index to WBS Sort" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Index: Index Will Serve as Sort",{{"Index", "WBS Sort"}})
in
    #"Renamed Column: Named Index to WBS Sort"
```

Although I did not perform this step above, I would suggest deleting the three **WBS - Copy...** columns. They are useless after attaining the sort column. After this, go ahead and *Close and Apply* your changes in Power Query. In the report view of Power BI Desktop, select your **WBS** column. Choose the *Sort by column* dropdown in the *Column tools* tab, then select the newly derived **WBS Sort** column as the sorting column. See example below.

[image]

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: This looks great, but some of my WBS strings can be of the format 1.1.1.1 and 1.2.1.1.1. Is there a straightforward addition to the above to account for further granulation?

Comment: I wouldn't see why not. When you split the columns by delimiter, ensure that you select the option to split by all instances of the delimiter. (In this case, the period.) As far as the sort order goes, simply sort the split columns in Power Query in the correct hierarchical order.